# How to maintain scroll position when navigating back from a document

Tags: 2010, postback, excel-web-access-webpart

I have an Access Web Datasheet being used to display data from a Sharepoint 2010 Document Library. We access the document to view but when we navigate back to the Access Web Datasheet view the page has scrolled all the way back to the top and any applied filters have been taken away as well. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Open the document in a new window. If you can mess with the markup just add a `target="_blank"`, otherwise, you can instruct your users to use the middle mouse button to click on the links.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work clicking the scroll wheel. Other then that I'm not sure what middle button you are referring to. I tried right clicking as well but to no avail. The datasheet doesn't allow me to select "Open in a new tab".